# Two database tables storing email addresses, one of the addresses to be set to default

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a SQL Server database that contains two tables both of which contain email addresses. One contains email addresses that have been created by the organisation for the users, the other contains users personal email addressees.

We want to give the user the option to set one of these as the preferred contact email address. What would be the best way to represent this in the database?

As far as I can see I could: -

1. Create the same field on each table called is_preferred. Create a stored procedure to set the correct field in the corresponding table that the email addresses belongs to, ensuring that any other email addresses are not set to default
2. Create a new table that stores the ID of the preferred mail addresses. I would need to have a 'mail type' in this table as well to know which table I need to lookup the mail address in. I.e. personal or organisation email.

Which solution do you think would be best?

A user could have multiple organisation mail addresses as well as multiple personal email addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to modal this:

[image]

NOTE: If there are no *(specific fields)* or *(specific constraints)*, just merge all three email tables into one.

The EMAIL's composite PK establishes an ordering of emails at the level of the given person. You can then simply introduce a convention that the first row relative to that ordering is the "preferred" e-mail.

---

Here is another way (if you want simpler keys):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would create an e-mail address table with columns `email_id`, `email_address`, `employee_id`, and `type` (a flag for personal or organizational). I would then add the column `preferred` to my employee table, and have it store the appropriate `email_id`.

I would assume email addresses must be DISTINCT, so you likely could scrap id all together, in favor of the address as the key.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer having a separate table with

```
UserId, PreferredOrgEmailId, PreferredPersonalEmailId
```

This whole situation is far from ideal but if you had to work with it... separate table would work. So you can use FK to make sure your data doesn't go out of sync. Also, maybe a check constraint to make sure you can only have one email id (Org or Personal) populated.

Actually storing the email address in this new table would be 2NF.